# Is there a good solution for zipping large s3 buckets

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an amazon s3 bucket setup for my media galleries and can't find a solution.

I am running a Linux server and using Laravel (PHP). I have the awscli and have attempted several different ways to download all objects, zip them up, and then notify email process is complete.

I have tried the below and many other options to no avail.

```
exec('aws s3 sync s3://bucket/subfolder /home/path/app/storage/subfolder')

$output = shell_exec(
  'aws s3 sync s3://bucket/subfolder /home/path/app/storage/subfolder', $output, $return
)

if ( ! $return) { /** do something here */ } else { /** process failed */ }
```

Doing the way above server times out as they can be a couple of GB and it fails.

The final goal is to get the bucket/folder in a zipfile back on s3.